# Процедуры и сложные запросы на MySQL и т.д.

Tags: mysql

Прочитал несколько книг, понаписывал запросов

Все в стиле веб разработчиков

Джойны и сложные запросы освоил

Слышал что в sql можно писать функции и процедуры, это правда? если да то как это делается?

И что еще мне предстоит выучить чтобы знать о MySQL все с точки зрения составления запросов?

И что обычно используют для тестирования производительности запросов?

Comment: не забывайте еще о [курсорах][1].


  [1]: http://www.zoonman.ru/library/mysql_cursors.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правда, функции и процедуры очень часто используются в MySQL
[Mysql Ref Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)
Знать все не получится, sql уже достаточно суровый, лучше отталкиваться от поступающих задач.

Для тестирования производительности можно использовать [Profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html)